# UIViewController Size doesn´t work

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7

Hi im currently developing an Universal app for iPhone, iPod and iPad. I have all view controllers in both storyboards set to Inferred. It works fine on iPhone Retina and on all iPads but when you put it in landscape mode it gets all messed upp and on the iphone 3,5 inch simulator the bottom gets cut off. How can i fix this? Do i have do create seperate view controllers for landscape mode and iphone 3,5? And the write some code that recognizes if its in landscape mode and iphone 4? I thought this worked automatically. Or have i done something wrong?

Comment: you need to understand AutoLayout https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no quick fix/answer to your question. 
Since the screen size is different while using horizontal and vertical orientations - it is simply not the same canvas and thus you will need to do some manual work to set it right.

**Strategy 1.**
Assuming your layout is simple - there are not too many elements and all elements can theoretically fit both horizontal and vertical screen size:

You should use auto layout from the Interface builder - Look at an excellent video from WWDC
https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/ 
(video 406 - Taking Control of Auto Layout in Xcode 5) 
In few words - you set spacers to your elements, aligning them to the end of your view (dynamically), therefore you can make your element shrink and move automatically respecting the current screen orientation.

**Strategy 2.**
Assuming your UI is complex and will not fit both orientations:
have a different xib file for horizontal and vertical views, this can take some time, but it is a solid solution that always looks good.
You simply need to track changes in orientation and load the appropriate xib.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem will only be solved if you use Autolayouting and for that you need to go through some tutorials

[Ray's Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

[Another Very well explained tutorial](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2015112&seqNum=2)

Going through the above articles will definately help you in solving your problem